# MariaDB won't start - fails to check integrity

Tags: mysql, mac-osx, innodb, mariadb

I have a MariaDB installed with `brew` in my macbook. Worked fine till today.
All of a sudden it wound not start:

```
-> mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
ERROR!
```

also, if I issue `mysql -uroot` or any other mysql command I'm getting `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")` which was pretty confusing and I spent hours figuring out where `mysql.sock` went. When in reality it simple wasn't created since DB never started. I found that out after looking at log file. It was full of errors of this kind:

`InnoDB: Error: trying to access update undo rec field 48 in index "PRIMARY" of table... InnoDB: but index has only 25 fields`

or

`2015-11-04 12:30:20 7000008b1000  InnoDB: Error: trying to access tablespace 893002339 page no. 1751475051,
InnoDB: but the tablespace does not exist or is just being dropped.`

Tons of errors like this. I'm guessing my DB got corrupted at some point and MariaDB fails to perform integrity check.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling MariaDB, errors persist, because databases are still here...

If there's an easy fix I'll be glad to accept it, but if not I'm ready to drop all of my DBs (I've got backups) and start over with fresh `brew` install of MariaDB. All of my databases and log files reside in `/usr/local/var/mysql` if that if of any help.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would try (re)moving all your databases and import them again after MariaDB starts up again. The errors indicate a corrupted database indeed, so it's best to start and troubleshoot from the bottom and import your databases 1 by 1 until you find the culprit.

Comment: @Oldskool thanks for the suggestion. Can I just start removing the db folders from ``/usr/local/var/mysql`` ? Aren't they indexed somewhere?

Comment: I believe that with MariaDB the indexes also reside in the same folder as your database itself, so if you move them out of the way, the indexes should be gone as well.

Comment: @Oldskool yay! Great success! Now put it into an answer and I'll gladly accept it

Comment: Good to hear! I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors indicate a corrupted database indeed, so it's best to start and troubleshoot from the bottom.

I would try (re)moving all your databases and then see if MariaDB starts up again (it should). Then import your databases 1 by 1 until you find the problematic database and use your last good backup to restore that one.